# can someone help me after i run the composer install

Tags: laravel

config file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkHF.png)
@my appService provider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCs3R.png)

can someone tell me about this problem after I input composer install that problem says and now I cant migrate

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   Database (C:\xampp\htdocs\shop2\database\db.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys=1)
```

when I run php artisan migrate this problem show

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'config/database.php' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t
able_schema = config/database.php and table_name = migrations)

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'config/database.php'

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'config/database.php'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your database config of your `.env` in your question. Configs like `DB_CONNECTION`, `DB_DATABASE`

Comment: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   Database (C:\xampp\htdocs\shop2\database\db.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys=1)

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your database config. Maybe post the contents of the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty file with name of `db.sqlite` in your database folder of the app. Then, run `php artisan migrate`, It will be filled by the app.